# Custom product note on checkout but only to products with specific stock status

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I have created a custom stock status for preorders.

How can I make custom notes appear on checkout next to products, but only one with the status 'Preorder'?

I mean something like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRNDO.jpg

I want it to be something like:

This is a preorder. Shipping after the release (date).

And date will display value of product attribute with 'release' slug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'woocommerce_cart_item_extra', 10, 3);

function woocommerce_cart_item_extra($item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key) {

    if ('preorder' === $cart_item['data']->get_stock_status()) {

        $release_attr = $cart_item['data']->get_attribute('pa_release');

        $item_name .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i style='color:gray;'>" . __('This is a preorder. Shipping after the release', 'woocommerce') . " ( $release_attr )</i>";
    }

    return $item_name;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create some selector for this element so that it can be styled using CSS?

Comment: Update the line as below     `$item_name .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id='out-stock' style='color:gray;'>" . __('This is a preorder. Shipping after the release', 'woocommerce') . " ( $release_attr )</span>";`

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it.